# JavaScript download a file if prompt password is true

Tags: javascript, html, button, download, passwords

I want to download a file if user enters the correct password

I have a button in my html file:

`<button onclick="password()"><h3>Code</h3> </a>`

in my .js file, here is the function:

```
function password() {
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password");
    if (password === "password") {
        //download the file
    }
    else {
        alert("Password incorrect");
    }
}
```

the file to be downloaded is located at "../file/file.txt"

I am unsure how to download the file once user enters the correct file

Comment: I hope this is just an exercise, not real code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
<a id="download" style="display: none" 
    href="../file/file.text" 
    download>Download</a>


function password() {
    var password = prompt("Please enter the password");
    if (password === "password") {
        document.getElementById('download').click();
    }
    else {
        alert("Password incorrect");
    }
}
```